# Gradle ShadowJar with Other SourceSet Resources

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I am using the ShadowJar Gradle plugin to build a Jar containing all of the source files in the  `src/main/java` directory and other Jar files in a `lib` directory and it is working fine. What I need is another ShadowJar task, a `devShadowJar` task, that will instead of pulling in a JSON file in the `src/main/resources` folder, it will pull in a JSON file in the `src/dev/resources` folder.

I added this to the `build.gradle` file to define the `dev` source set:

```
sourceSets {
    dev
}
```

But now I am not sure how to create a `devShadowJar` task to use the `dev` JSON resource instead of the JSON resource file located in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: can you show your build.gradle file?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

try playing around this:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

task devShadowJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    zip64 true
    from './build/classes/java/main'
    from project.configurations.compile
    from './src/dev/resources' // or wherever the resources and up under ./build
}
```